# How to map over a list of lists in dataframe in R? (tidyverse pipeline)

Tags: r, list, dictionary, tidyverse

I'm trying to add the elements of an integer vector, which are nested in a two-level list.

I came up with this solution, but I think it's a little uncommon, so I am looking for another alternative:

```
df <- tibble(
  a = list(list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4)), list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4)))
)

df %>% 
  mutate(
   b = a %>% modify_depth(2, sum) %>% map(unlist)
  )
```

which gives, and it's the right solution. But I am looking to use more of a `map` solution and less of `modify`.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a          b        
  <list>     <list>   
1 <list [2]> <dbl [2]>
2 <list [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

Solution in view mode:

[image]

Comment: There is `map_depth`

Comment: `map` doesn't work with nested list.

Comment: I would recommend to use `rrapply` as it works on any depth `rrapply::rrapply(df$a, f = function(x) sum(x))`

Comment: Would you say the only solution is `*_depth`?  (only purrr)

Comment: because `map` works similar to `lapply` in looping over a list.  If the list is nested, you need nested map, which is basically the `_depth` does.

Comment: This gives same output as your `df %>% mutate(b = rrapply::rrapply(a, f = sum) %>% map(unlist))` with advantage that you don't have to specify the depth

Comment: Can you specify the issue with using `_modify` function

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we don't know the depth and the `list` elements have multiple depths or same depth, `rrapply` would be more general

```
libary(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(b = rrapply::rrapply(a, f = sum) %>%
                   map(unlist))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  a          b        
#  <list>     <list>   
#1 <list [2]> <dbl [2]>
#2 <list [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

---

also, there is `map_depth`.  According to `?map_depth`

> map_depth() allows to apply .f to a specific depth level of a nested vector

which is same as `modify_depth`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
      b = a %>% 
              map_depth(2, sum) %>% 
              map(unlist) )
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, by any chance, Do you give tutorials? It seems you know a lot of this stuff and I want to learn more.